# bootstrap dropdown navbar not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i got a problem with bootstrap dropdown

here is my full code 
https://github.com/PowerChaos/kb/

to explain it easy

```
 <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if i switch the jquery.js above bootstrap.js , then the top navbar dropdown does not work

below are some functions in the script to see who is logged in and display based on login
`(u()) (a()) and (s()) are functions to user/staff/admin sessions`

html code of sidebar below

```
<?php
if (u())
{
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../home">Knowledge Base</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <?php
      if (s())
      {
?>      
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Post Menu
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="../s/nieuw">Nieuwe Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="../s/bewerk">Bewerk Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="../s/lijst">zie all posten</a></li>        
        </ul>
      </li>
<?php       
      }
      ?>
          <?php
      if (a())
      {

?>                  
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin Menu
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">                  
        <li><a href="../a/gebruikers">Gebruikers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<?php       
      }
      ?>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['naam'] ?>
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../pass">wachtwoord</a></li>
          <li><a href="../logout">Log Uit</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <!-- Dynamic SiteBar -->
<div class="navbar-fixed-left">
<ul id="tree1">
<?php
require(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT")."/functions/database.php");
    try{    
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hc");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}//end try
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<h2><font color=red>';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die ('</h2></font> ');
}
    foreach($result as $info) {
echo "<li>$info[naam]";
echo "<ul>";

    try{
$hc = $info[id];        
$stmthc = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shc where hc =:hc");
$stmthc->execute(array(':hc' => $hc));
$resultsub = $stmthc->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}//end try
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<h2><font color=red>';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die ('</h2></font> ');
}

foreach($resultsub as $sub) {
echo "<li>$sub[naam]";
echo "<ul>";

    try{
$subhc = $sub[id];      
$stmtsubhc = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts where shc =:subhc");
$stmtsubhc->execute(array(':subhc' => $subhc));
$resultpost = $stmtsubhc->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}//end try
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<h2><font color=red>';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die ('</h2></font> ');
}

foreach($resultpost as $post) {
echo "<li><a href='../post/$post[id]'>$post[naam]</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
}
?>
</ul>           
</div>
<!-- Dynamic SiteBar -->    
<?php
}
?>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container content">
```

Comment: can you be a little more elaborate pls, if what is switched, what doesn't work in BS dropdown navbar ? may be a non functional Fiddle code will help

Comment: by switching the `jquery.js` above `bootstrap.js` then the header dropdown does not work  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header">`  if i put `jquery.js` below `bootstrap.js` then everything works exept in console it says `bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: Hmm ok first of all, for bootstrap to work it definitely requires jQuery so include it before bootstrap. Following this order you need to fix what is broken & why is the navbar not working. This is a different issue. but first order should always be **jquery > bootstrap**

Comment: thank you, on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3t42fbw3/2/ it does work but on my script it does not work if i include jquery first , then the `topnavbar dropdown` fails to work , it only works if i put the jsquery under the bootstrap, what do i need to change then to get the dropdown working when jsquery is before bootstrap ?

Comment: ok can you tell me when you click the dropdown(when it fails), what is the browser console error that comes(Ctrl + Shift + C).

Comment: there is no browser error :(

Comment: can i get a link of your app live, hosted somewhere. Where I can check the final rendered web application.

Comment: Ok got it, you can delete the previous credentials comment now for your security purposes if you want.

Comment: Try putting the CSS in the head of the document and the JQuery/BootstrapJS includes at the bottom of the document but before the closing body tag. -- Also for both <script src=""></script> tags, add the following to make it appear as so, <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

Comment: this gives me a lot more errors if i do that in the footer ,  `jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
jquery.ui.shake.js:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
VM70:52 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treed is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overview of how bootstrap dropdown works**

When you click the `dropdown-toggle` element, bootstrap adds a class called **open** to its parent element & that's what makes it visible.

**Reason why its not working**

For some reason which is weird, your dropdown is not getting the class open on it when clicked. When I explicitly add the class in the debugger it works.

**Solution**

You can write your own piece of code which adds the class "open" to the dropdown like so:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if(parent.hasClass('open')) { 
    parent.removeClass('open'); 
  } else {
     parent.addClass('open');
  }
});
```

Add this after you initialise your treeviews or anywhere after `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Thank you , this solution also works for summernote dropdown ( wysiwig editor )

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery 1.11.1 version and place the scripts before the links:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/styles.css"/>
```